# How to handle special characters in comments and hard coded strings in python file?

Tags: python, string, encoding, comments, special-characters

This question aims at the following two scenarios:

1. You want to add a string with special characters to a variable:

   `special_char_string = "äöüáèô"`
2. You want to allow special characters in comments.

   `# This a comment with special characters in it: äöà etc.`

At the moment I handle this this way:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
special_char_string = "äöüáèô".decode('utf8')
# This a comment with special characters in it: äöà etc.
```

Works fine.

Is this the recommended way? Or is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Why `.decode()` ? Define a unicode string! `u"äöüáèô"`

Comment: @phant0m, I am confused. Do you suggest, that `u"äöüáèô"` is the same as `"äöüáèô".decode('utf8')` in any case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python will check the first or second line for an emacs/vim-like encoding specification.

> More precisely, **the first or second
>   line** must match the regular
>       expression "coding[:=]\s*([-\w.]+)". The first
>   group of this
>       expression is then interpreted as encoding name. If the encoding
>       is unknown to Python, an error is raised during compilation.

Source: [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

(A BOM would also make Python interpret the source as UTF-8.

I would recommend, you use this over `.decode('utf8')`

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
special_char_string = u"äöüáèô"
```

In any case, `special_char_string` will then contain a `unicode` object, no longer a `str`.
As you can see, they're both semantically equivalent:

```
>>> u"äöüáèô" == "äöüáèô".decode('utf8')
True
```

And the reverse:

```
>>> u"äöüáèô".encode('utf8')
'\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa8\xc3\xb4'
>>> "äöüáèô"
'\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa8\xc3\xb4'
```

There is a technical difference, however: if you use u"something", it will instruct the parser that there is a unicode literal, it should be a bit faster.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the recommended way for Python 2.x, see [PEP 0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).
In Python 3.x and above, the default encoding is UTF-8 and not ASCII, so you don't need this there. See [PEP 3120](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/#pep263).